# Exoplayer crashes on Nvidia Shield Android TV 2017

Tags: android, nvidia, android-tv, exoplayer

I cloned the ExoPlayer repo from github, built it and sideloaded it on my Nvidia Shield 2017. When I start the app, it immediately crashes. I just get 'The application stopped'.

If I run the same in Android TV emulator (Android TV (1080p) API 24, Android 7.0), it runs just fine.

The Nvidia Shield 2017 does not have a micro-usb port, only two regular usb-ports, so I don't know how to connect a usb cable to debug.

How can I find out what is causing this crash?

Thanks

Comment: You can debug through network using `adb connect <IP address>`